# Mismatched records redirected to error table?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, oracle

I am trying to write a SQL for ETL where I am trying to insert all the records from the source table to the target table where if any record doesn't match the target table schema(errors include exceeding column length of target and datatype mismatch) - as such rows should be redirected to a error which I can create dynamically with 'create as'

Wondering what would be the best way to design the SQL?

Comment: And you are using all the three `mysql`, `sqlserver` and `oracle` databases simultaneously?

Answer (score 1):

> (errors include exceeding column length of target and datatype mismatch) - as such rows should be redirected to a error which I can create dynamically with 'create as'

You don't have to do anything manually and no need to re-invent the wheel.

In Oracle, you could use the **DML Error Logging** feature which was introduced in **Oracle 10g Database Release 2**.

The basic syntax for error logging is:

```
LOG errors INTO error_logging_table_name [REJECT LIMIT <custom>/UNLIMITED];
```

To create the DML error logging table, you could:

1. Use the **CREATE_ERROR_LOG procedure** in the **DBMS_ERRLOG package**
   Or,
2. **Manually create** the table.

Let's look an example:

For demonstration, I am manually creating the **DML error logging table**:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE error_log_dml
  2    (
  3      ora_err_number$ NUMBER,
  4      ora_err_mesg$   VARCHAR2(2000),
  5      ora_err_rowid$ rowid,
  6      ora_err_optyp$ VARCHAR2(2),
  7      ora_err_tag$   VARCHAR2(2000)
  8    );

Table created.

SQL>
```

Let's test the **DML error logging feature**:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE t(A NUMBER NOT NULL);

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> INSERT INTO t VALUES(NULL) LOG errors INTO error_log_dml REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;

0 rows created.

SQL>
SQL> COLUMN ora_err_mesg$ format a75
SQL>
SQL> SELECT ora_err_mesg$ FROM error_log_dml;

ORA_ERR_MESG$
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("LALIT"."T"."A")

SQL>
```

So, yo can see the error is now logged in the table.

The above demonstrated feature works for:

- INSERT
- UPDATE
- DELETE
- MERGE

You might also be interested to look into the [**New `SQL*Plus` error logging feature**](http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2014/01/21/sqlplus-error-logging-new-feature-release-11-1/). It comes very handy when you use SQL*Plus to execute your scripts.

**UPDATE** Tagging your error messages.

For example,

```
SQL> DROP TABLE error_log_dml PURGE;

Table dropped.

SQL> DROP TABLE t PURGE;

Table dropped.

SQL> CREATE TABLE error_log_dml
  2    (
  3      ora_err_number$ NUMBER,
  4      ora_err_mesg$   VARCHAR2(2000),
  5      ora_err_rowid$ rowid,
  6      ora_err_optyp$ VARCHAR2(2),
  7      ora_err_tag$   VARCHAR2(2000)
  8    );

Table created.

SQL> CREATE TABLE t
  2    (A NUMBER
  3    );

Table created.

SQL> ALTER TABLE t ADD CONSTRAINT t_chk CHECK
  2  (
  3    a = 1
  4  )
  5  ;

Table altered.

SQL> INSERT INTO t VALUES
  2    (2
  3    ) LOG errors INTO error_log_dml(2) REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;

0 rows created.
```

Let's see the error table:

```
SQL> SELECT ora_err_mesg$,ORA_ERR_TAG$ FROM error_log_dml;

ORA_ERR_MESG$                                      ORA_ERR_TAG$
-------------------------------------------------- ---------------
ORA-02290: check constraint (LALIT.T_CHK) violated 2



SQL>
```

SO, I have used the **ORA_ERR_TAG$** column to insert the value which has thrown the error.

Comment: Hi Lalit, this captures the error but doesn't identify the records that caused the query to fail. Now those records which do not match the target column schema should be redirected to a new table created on the run time in order to accommodate these records.

Comment: @Sharktooth, See the update. Please mark it answered.